# What does `n` mean in Typed Racket?

Tags: racket, typed-racket

`n` shows up at the type level in error messages, what is it?

Example:

```lisp
(: trick (All (t u) ((U t (Listof u))  -> (Listof u)))) 
(define (trick x)
    (cond
      [(list? x) x]
     )      
)
```

Error with this `n` type:

```
Type Checker: type mismatch
  expected: (Listof u)
  given: (U (Listof u) (∩ (Pairof Any (Listof Any)) t)) in: x
```

I tried writing a type signature with `n` in it and using go-to-definition in Dr. Racket, but it says the symbol is not found.

Comment: It's not an "n", it's the "set intersection" symbol. [Documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/type-ref.html?q=%E2%88%A9#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fbase-types-extra..rkt%29._~e2~88~a9%29%29).

Comment: searching for "∩" brings up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not `n`, it's [`∩` (intersection)](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/type-ref.html?q=%E2%88%A9#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fbase-types-extra..rkt%29._%7Ee2%7E88%7Ea9%29%29).

[Thanks @willness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68191594/what-does-n-mean-in-typed-racket?noredirect=1#comment120530301_68191594) and [@molbdnilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68191594/what-does-n-mean-in-typed-racket?noredirect=1#comment120521990_68191594).

Comment: you're welcome. :) thanks [also due](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68191594/what-does-n-mean-in-typed-racket?noredirect=1#comment120521990_68191594) to [molbdnilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404970/molbdnilo).